# Current month in DropDownListFor by default in Asp.Net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have Months' `DropDownListFor` and I want to select current month as default I tried this two options

```
@{
var currentMonth = month.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == DateTime.Now.Month).Id;
}
```

**1.**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.monthId, new SelectList(month, "Id", "Name", currentMonth  ))
```

**2.**

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.monthId, month.Select(x => new SelectListItem
 { Text = x.Name.ToString(), Value = x.Id.ToString(), Selected = (x.Id == currentMonth ?true:false)})),
```

but neither works. 
How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Why has this quite basic question been upvoted three times ?

Comment: Show us your model ? At least the controller action that use the view

Comment: What is `month`, did you debug your code that the `currentMonth` variable is not null?

Comment: month is a List<Month>  which has Id as Value and Text as Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want with an option label then use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MonthId, new SelectList(month, "Id", "Name", Model.MonthId), "Select Month")
```

otherwise

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MonthId, new SelectList(month, "Id", "Name", Model.MonthId))
```

if that's also not work then try to assign month id in your model property

```
Model.MonthId = month.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == DateTime.Now.Month).Id;
```

and follow the above steps.

Answer (score 1):

You code is correct and `Selected = (x.Id == currentMonth ?true:false)}` is useless because you're binding to the property `monthId` of your model and this property is probably `null`. So at the top of your view add the following code after setting the `currentMonth` like below:

```
@{ 
    var currentMonth = month.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == DateTime.Now.Month).Id;
    Model.monthId = Model.monthId ?? currentMonth;
}
```